# How to keep parameter refness when passing to template taking variadic parameters?

Tags: reference, variadic-templates, d

The following breaks on the last line of `main()`:

```
import std.stdio, std.traits;

void main(){
        void test(ref int){}
        void delegate(Parameters!test) works = &test;
        template broken(Args...){
                void delegate(Args) broken;
        }
        broken!(Parameters!test) = &test; // Error: cannot implicitly convert expression &test of type void delegate(ref int _param_0) pure nothrow @nogc @safe to void delegate(int)
}
```

Is this intended? If so, how to work around it?

Comment: the language doesn't support what you want there in template argument lists (at least as far as I know).... what is your bigger-picture goal? there might be another way to express it.

Comment: Create a list of callbacks that I can extend, separated by parameter types. I guess like a compile-time hash map of runtime delegate lists. The problem comes when dealing with mixed functions and delegates, that's why I didn't pass the function type directly as I want both of them together - but I already found an ugly workaround: When adding a function, the "ctfe hash map" is indexed with `void delegate(Parameters!Fn)` instead of `Fn`. :D

Comment: hmmm, I might just do it with ctfe-generated wrapper functions instead of calling the function/delegate directly... but meh, idk.